# Lost CSS when authentifification

Tags: 8, theming

I made a custom theme based on bartik.

In this custom theme I add just one CSS file and a very simple specific view template file.

When I am connected with a user with 'Administrator' Role all is OK. It means that my customed class are loaded an applyed

But when i am connected with a user without 'Administrator' Role all is KO. It's like my customed class are not in the theme.

Any Idea ?

Comment: I am using Drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I found the problem.
The real problem was not because the user had this or this role.

But the view that i wanted to show had specifc class for some objects for user with Administrator Role.

Example :
an 'article' can have 'contextual' class when the user connected had Administrator Role.
the same 'article' does't have it  when the user connected didn't have Administrator Role.

I am new in drupal 8, so...